# apply partially last arg

Tags: elisp, apply

Is there something like `apply-partially`

```
(apply-partially FUN &rest ARGS)

Return a function that is a partial application of FUN to ARGS.
ARGS is a list of the first N arguments to pass to FUN.
The result is a new function which does the same as FUN, except that
the first N arguments are fixed at the values with with which this
function was called.
```

But with the "**last** N arguments are fixed"

Or "**all** arguments are fixed except wildcard" ie:

```
(defun foo (a b c))
(defalias 'fix-a-c-in-foo 'apply-partially-wildcard 'foo "a valuel" '_ "c value")
```

`_` - random symbol that means "wildcard"

Comment: Is the `fset`-form in the following `progn` sufficient for your purpose? `(progn (defun f(a1 a2) (+ a1 a2)) (let ((a2 2)) (fset #'f2 \`(lambda (_) (f _ ,a2)))) (f2 1))`

Comment: `subr.el` doesn't have one, but you could borrow one from here: https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-rpartial-fn-rest-args

Comment: The latter sounds like `-cut` from dash.el

Comment: @wasamasa `-cut` looks promising. Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have everything you need in the emacs-lisp core language with [`fset`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Cells.html#index-fset), [`lambda` expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lambda-Expressions.html#Lambda-Expressions) and [backticks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote).
The following source code is an extension of your second example.
The comma expression allows you to easily substitute something in a back-tick quoted `lambda` expression
and you can assign that expression to a symbol's function-cell with `fset`.

```el
(defun foo (a b c d)
  (message "a=%s b=%s c=%s d=%s" a b c d))

(let ((fix-a "a-value"))
  (fset #'fix-a-c-in-foo `(lambda (_d _b) (foo ,fix-a _b "c-value" _d)))
  )

(fix-a-c-in-foo "new-d-value" "new-b-value")
```

I have added one more argument to `foo` to have at least two fix parameters and two "template" parameters. The template parameters `_b` and `_d` are swapped which would not be possible if you just had one symbol for all such parameters. Furthermore, I've wrapped the `fset` (corresponding to your `defalias`) in my version in a `let` to show that we can use the value of a local variable as fixed parameter in the template.
The part of the above source code that solves your problem is just:

```el
(fset #'fix-a-c-in-foo `(lambda (_d _b) (foo ,fix-a _b "c-value" _d)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Being surprised by let - passing settings by fset outside.

Answer (score 5):

`apply-partially` was most useful back when Emacs did not have lexical binding, since it let you build "closures".  But for your example, you don't even need a closure:

```
(defalias 'fix-a-c-in-foo (lambda (b) (foo "a_value" b "c_value")))
```

for a more general case, OTOH you do need closures, so you'll want to add `-*- lexical-binding:t -*-` to the first line of your file and then you can do things like:

```
(defun whatever (a c)
  (lambda (b) (foo a b c)))
```

Also, note that `(lambda (x y) (foo a x y))` is implemented more efficiently than `(apply-partially #'foo a)`.

Comment: Why can't we use your function `whatever` with dynamic binding? For this special example I do not see a relevant difference between dynamic and lexical binding. Furthermore, Is something wrong with my answer? (I understand that I could/should use `defalias` instead of `fset`. But, beside of that...)

Comment: Your answer is not *wrong*, but backquoting lambdas means you're generating source code at run-time, which prevents that code from being byte-compiled.

Comment: Indeed, `mapcar` probably won't bind dynamically bind its own `a` or `c` so my example also worked in 99% of the cases with dynamic scoping.  I've changed my example to really need lexical scoping.